# jquery dropdown menu bind mouseout timer is not working

Tags: jquery

What I wanted to achieve is: Once click on INFO text, the sub-menu show up. When mouse is still on the sub-menu, it remains there. Mouse out the sub-menu, it will be disappeared.

But in my code, the second part does not work.
Even my mouse is still on the sub-menu items, the menu is disappeared after the time out value.

```
var timeout    = 500;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function jsddm_open2()
{  
jsddm_canceltimer();
   jsddm_close();
   ddmenuitem = jQuery(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');
   ddmenuitem = jQuery(this).find('ul').toggle();}   

function jsddm_close()
{  if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');}

function jsddm_timer()
{  closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);}

function jsddm_canceltimer()
{  if(closetimer)
   {  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
      closetimer = null;}}

jQuery(document).ready(function()
{    
jQuery('#INFO > ul > li').bind('click', jsddm_open2);
jQuery('#INFO > ul > li > ul > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer);  
});
```

HTML markup:

```
<div id="INFO">
        <ul>
            <li>INFO
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>                            
                </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#INFO ul{padding: 0;}
#INFO ul li{display: block; width: 200px; padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 1px;}

#INFO ul li ul{position: absolute; z-index: 999; visibility: hidden; top: 20px; padding: 0px; left: 6px; border: 1px solid #888; border-top: none; height: auto !important; width: 180px; display: none;}
#INFO ul li ul li{ padding: 5px 20px; background: #1d7177; width: 140px; display: block;}
#INFO ul li ul li:hover{background: #000;}
#INFO a{ color: #fff; padding: 0px; height: auto;}
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Try mouseleave instead of mouseout http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/. It could be to do with the bubbling of events. So for example when you mouseover one of your anchors, it calls mouseout on the list item.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But still got the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
jQuery('#INFO > ul > li > ul').bind('mouseleave',  jsddm_timer);
```

Here's an [article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1805-jQuery-Events-MouseOver-MouseOut-vs-MouseEnter-MouseLeave.htm) explaining why mouseleave works and mouseout doesn't. Also notice I changed `#INFO > ul > li > ul > li` to `#INFO > ul > li > ul` as mouseleave would be called as you switched li's.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any fading and whatnot effects, just play with CSS :

HTML :

```
<div id="INFO">
    <p>INFO</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>                            
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
div#INFO > ul {
    display: none;
}

div#INFO:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#css").css("text-decoration",'none');
        $("#css").css("color",'black');
        $("#css").css("font-size",'24px');
        $("#css").css("font-family","'Comic Sans MS', cursive");
                            $(".a").css("text-decoration",'none');
                            $(".a").css("color",'black');
                            $(".a").css("font-size",'16px');
                            $(".a").css("font-family","'Comic Sans MS', cursive");
                            $(".a").css("text-decoration",'none');


$("#slide").hide();

        $("#slide").css("position","relative");
        $("#slide").css("top",'-30px');
        $("#slide").css("height",'200px');
        $("#slide").css("width",'150px');
        $("#slide").css("border",'groove');
        $("#slide").css("list-style",'none');
        $("#slide").css("border-radius","10px");


                    $(".toggle").mouseenter(function()
                    {
                        //$("#slide").slideToggle("slow");
                        $("#slide").show(1000);
                    });


                    $("#slide").mouseleave(function(){
                        $("#slide").hide(1000); 
                    })

                    })

</script>
<body id="body">
<a href="" id="css" class="toggle">Slidedown</a>

<div id="slide">
<li>&nbsp;</li>
<hr />
<li><a class="a" href="#">Google</a></li>
<li><a class="a" href="#">Youtube</a></li>
<li><a class="a" href="#">Gmail</a></li>
<li><a class="a" href="#">Facebook</a></li>
<li><a class="a" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
<li><a class="a" href="http://www.google.com">Slider</a></li>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Posting the exact same answer, with no explanation or indication of how it fits each of the 4 different questions... not good

Comment: Sorry for that but it will solve ur problem in making a drop down menu